# Is there an idiomatic way of setting constraints on parameters in R?

Tags: r, regression, anova, constraint

Let's say I have 2 categorical variables `foo` and `bar` that have the same 4 levels A, B, C and D
I have a response variable $Y$, and I want to fit the following model (without intercept):
$$Y = \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 + \beta_3 x_3 + \beta_4 x_4 + \beta_5 x_5 + \beta_6 x_6 + \beta_7 x_7 + \beta_8 x_8 + \epsilon$$
Where:

- `foo` is one-hot encoded over $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$ and $x_4$
- `bar` is one-hot encoded over $x_5$, $x_6$, $x_7$ and $x_8$

I want to set the following constraints on the parameters of my model:

- $\beta_1 + \beta_5 = 0$
- $\beta_2 + \beta_6 = 0$
- $\beta_3 + \beta_7 = 0$
- $\beta_4 + \beta_8 = 0$

Now my model is:
$$Y = \beta_1 (x_1 - x_5) + \beta_2 (x_2 - x_6) + \beta_3 (x_3 - x_7) + \beta_4 (x_4 - x_8) + \epsilon$$

It is still over-parameterized, so let's arbitrarily set another constraint $\beta_1 = 0$ so the other coefficients will be interpreted relative to $\beta_1$.
The final model is:
$$Y = \beta_2 (x_2 - x_6) + \beta_3 (x_3 - x_7) + \beta_4 (x_4 - x_8) + \epsilon$$

Do I have to manually encode my variables?
Or is there a more idiomatic way of specifying constraints on parameters?

Comment: Many statistical software platforms will automatically select a basis of variables for you. If you want to use *these* particular variables then the software won't be able to read your mind; you will need to construct the variables $x_2-x_6,$ *etc,* and pass them to the software.

Comment: I know R can't read my mind, but my question is: **is there a way of telling R the constraints $\beta_1 = 0$, $\beta_5 = 0$, $\beta_2 + \beta_6 = 0$, $\beta_3 + \beta_7 = 0$ and $\beta_4 + \beta_8 = 0$ without encoding the variables myself?**  
By using contrasts maybe?

Comment: It sounds like you already know the answer to that.  There appear to be many related posts here on CV: see https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+contrast+regression.